# jQuery has() not working as intended

Tags: jquery, iteration

Maybe I'm understanding it wrong but shouldn't this has() work in this situation? What am I doing wrong?

```
  $("#count").on("click", function(){
    $(".item").each(function( index, element ){
      $(element).text( index + 1 );

      /*** this line does nothing ****/
      $(element).has(".special").css("background", "black");

      if( index + 1  == 4  || index + 1  == 8 ){
         $(this).css("background", "#A5C663");
      }
    })
  })
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="grid">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item special"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item special"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
```

This is not working either:

```
$(this).has(".special").css("background", "black");
```

Or:

```
$(".item).has(".special").css("background", "black");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `has` with `is`.

- [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) is about this set of elements
- [`has`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) is about the descendants

Comment: I understand. It works for example I add a paragraph with the class of "special" inside of ".item". Thank you. Accepting when it allows me.